# Get files hidden in msbuild from Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild

A file can be hidden from Visual Studio using the "Visible" metadata, e.g.

```
<Compile Include="Hidden.cs">
  <Visible>false</Visible>
</Compile>
```

The file is still built as part of the project, but isn't displayed in Visual Studio - it's not included in the hierarchy information.

Is it possible to get at this file programmatically, in Visual Studio? E.g. by getting access to the msbuild object model and getting all Items with the Visible metadata set?

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to achieve, you can use XDocument and query the .csproj file, you should be able to pull out any/all hidden files.

Comment: I was trying to get at the msbuild object model from within Visual Studio. So, if I was a VS addin, find the hidden files - they're excluded from the VSHierarchy interfaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if there's a better way to get the msbuild object model from a VS project, but I can get all of the currently loaded projects from an msbuild static property:

[`Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ProjectCollection.GlobalProjectCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.build.evaluation.projectcollection.globalprojectcollection.aspx)

And then I can call `GetLoadedProjects(path)` passing in the path of the project I'm trying to get. From there I can interrogate the returned `Project` object to get at the items.

Answer (score 1):

The following target lists hidden files:

```
<Target Name="ShowHiddenFiles">
    <Message Text="'%(Compile.FullPath)'" Condition="%(Compile.Visible) == false" />
</Target>
```